# Receiving ORA-06531 Reference to uninitialized collection error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am running a function that imports a file and I am receiving the following Oracle error:

ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at "BANINST1.SZKPERT", line 186

I have read on other answers that I need to initialize a collection to avoid this error.  However, I am unsure what collection I need to initialize and what syntax should I use.  Below is the function:

```
function f_get_pert_examinees (p_filename varchar2)
return baninst1.scf_pert_test_examinee_nt
pipelined 
is
lv_filename     CONSTANT varchar2(50) := p_filename;

lv_examinee_tab lt_download_tab_type;
lv_remote_data  clob;
lv_char         varchar2(1);
lv_eol          boolean := false;
lv_tablen       binary_integer;
lv_list         szkftpx.t_string_table;
type lt_field_tab_type is table of varchar2(50) index by binary_integer;
lv_field_tab    lt_field_tab_type;
type lt_remote_data_tab_type is table of clob index by binary_integer;
lv_remote_data_tab lt_remote_data_tab_type;
begin
  begin
  -- Connect to FTP site and get data from file.
  lv_connection := szkftpx.login(lv_site, lv_port, lv_user, lv_pass);
  szkftpx.ascii(p_conn => lv_connection);

  -- Get a list of files.
  szkftpx.nlst(p_conn  => lv_connection,
               p_dir   => './' || substr(lv_filename,1,20) || '*',
               p_list  => lv_list);

  -- Loop through the files.
  for file_index in 1..lv_list.count
  loop
    begin
      lv_remote_data_tab (file_index) 
        := szkftpx.get_remote_ascii_data (
             p_conn => lv_connection,
             p_file => lv_list(file_index));
    exception
      when others then null;
    end;
  end loop;

  szkftpx.logout(lv_connection);
exception
  when others then null;
end;
```

/* HERE IS LINE 186, RIGHT AT THE FOR LOOP BELOW.  IT LOOKS LIKE I MAY NEED TO INITIALIZE THE COLLECTION "lv_examinee_tab" BUT I'M NOT SURE HOW OR WHERE IN THE CODE I SHOULD DO THIS.
*/

```
for file_index2 in 1..lv_list.count
loop
  if lv_remote_data_tab.exists (file_index2)
  then
    if dbms_lob.getlength(lv_remote_data_tab (file_index2)) > 0
    then
      -- Parse clob into collection.
      lv_examinee_tab := f_clob2tab (lv_remote_data_tab (file_index2));

      -- Loop through collection
      for i in 1..lv_examinee_tab.count
      loop
        lv_field_tab.delete;

        -- Parse each record in collection, putting comma-separated fields in field collection.
        declare
          lv_string        varchar2(2000):=replace(lv_examinee_tab(i),',',', '); 
        begin
          for r in
            (select regexp_substr(lv_string,'[^,]+',1,level) my_field   
               from dual   
            connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(lv_string,'[^,]+')) + 1)   
          loop
            lv_field_tab(lv_field_tab.count + 1) := trim(r.my_field);  
          end loop;
        end;

        if lv_field_tab(1) <> 'Last Modified'
        then
          -- Assemble field in a record and send back to caller.
          pipe row (baninst1.scf_pert_test_examinee(
                      lv_field_tab(1),
                      lv_field_tab(2),
                      lv_field_tab(3),
                      lv_field_tab(4),
                      lv_field_tab(5),
                      lv_field_tab(6),
                      lv_field_tab(7),
                      lv_field_tab(8),
                      lv_field_tab(9),
                      lv_field_tab(10),
                      lv_field_tab(11),
                      lv_field_tab(12),
                      lv_field_tab(13),
                      lv_field_tab(14),
                      lv_field_tab(15),
                      lv_field_tab(16),
                      lv_field_tab(17)));
        end if;
      end loop;
    end if;
  end if;
end loop;

end f_get_pert_examinees;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks more like `lv_list` is not initialized.
You don't get the error at first place because of `exception
  when others then null;`

You can initialize it with

```
lv_list := szkftpx.t_string_table();
```

In order to create an empty list. However, I assume you should do it like this:

```
IF lv_list IS NOT NULL THEN
   for file_index2 in 1..lv_list.count loop
   ...
END IF;
```

Comment: I added the initialization statement "lv_list := szkftpx.t_string_table();" as you suggested right after the first "begin" statement in my function.  However, the for loop "for file_index in 1..lv_list.count" does not execute the statements within the loop since the value of "lv_list.count" is zero prior to the for loop.